# Nested Routing - current_user in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, nested-resources

I have to models `User` and `Blog`. Their respective urls are:

```
test.com/u/user_name   # User
test.com/blogs         # Blog
```

I'm trying to achieve that the blogs are nested to the user which created it. E.g. `test.com/u/user_name/blogs` and for an article `test.com/u/user_name/blogs/article_name`.

But the index for all blogs should respond to: `test.com/blogs`.

right now my routes are like this:

```
resources :users do
  resources :blogs, except: [:index]
end 

resources :blogs, only: [:index]
```

Which doesn't work.. What am i missing?

Comment: does the users url work? you didn't set in path in your routes.

Answer (score 0):

**Routes**

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :blogs, only: :index #-> domain.com/blogs -> blogs#index
resources :users, path: "u" do #-> domain.com/u/:id
   resources :blogs #-> domain.com/u/:user_id/blogs/:id
end
```

You'll want to look up about the [`path` argument](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#translated-paths) for your routes

As a rule of thumb, you'll want to include any "non conventional" paths at the bottom of the routes file. As the routes are determined from the top to bottom, if you're capturing obscure paths near the top of the file, you'll end up causing conflict with your other routes